# How to hide top menubar bar. Needed for the wine

Tags: unity, wine, resolution, games, workspaces

Ubuntu unity use top bar like MAC. Nice. But, how to get the top bar hide?

Im using Wine or Playonlinux program. And im using virtual desktop in my screen. Big problem is a virtual desktop not fit the screen. Virtual screen size is 1024 * 768. Screen size is 1360*768. this 768 not fit the screen. Game using virtual desktop.

This 768 resolution does not fit the window because it will hit the top bar. And the game goes to another workspace window. It makes some games to play hard, when game menus and toolbars is a bottom in second workspace. Please add Ubuntu options to hide top bar.

im using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: There is a way to do this in GNOME, I remember, just let me think...

Comment: This might help... http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1862761

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I've had several moments like this. There aren't many options to be frank and none of them are ideal.

- Run the game in windowed mode (inside the virtual desktop) and run the desktop at full resolution. It will become full-screen (over the bars) and then you can get the game window as big as you can. Not all games allow this but it's leaps and bounds more simple than the rest of the options.
- [Hack compiz so it targets your Wine window for fullscreen mode](/a/22296/449) (doesn't always work if the application changes resolution after loading)
- [Run the game in a separate X server instance](/questions/3981/). Arguably better performance because Compiz isn't compositing the window.
- Use KDE. Kwin (the window manager) can force windows to become always-on-top and drop their borders at the same time. This has certainly simplified things for me but it's a big emotional investment.