# Top menu bar is sliding down after hover

Tags: 14.04, menu-bar, autohide

I would like to hide a top menu bar. I mean when I hover the mouse over it, the top bar will slide down (like the side bar). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I can find says that it can't be done with Unity.

[How to hide top menubar bar. Needed for the wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258679/how-to-hide-top-menubar-bar-needed-for-the-wine)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2132759

You can do this with Gnome Shell, though.